# When Big cone= Ample cone ? 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex projective variety (you may assume it is smooth, or has mild singularities, is simply connected or any other assumption which makes you happy)

Let $Big(X)$ and $Amp(X)$ be the cone of big and ample divisors respectively.
Both are open cones in $N^1(X)$.

What can we say if we know they are equal? Note that in general $Amp(X) \subseteq Big(X)$ and the former is smaller when there are effective divisors which are not nef.

Comment: Dear Mohammad, I don't have a general answer to your question: I just wanted to mention that one situation in which Amp=Big is the case of abelian varieties (of any dimension). In that case, every effective divisor is nef because of translations, so the nef cone and (pseudo-)effective cone have equal interiors: that is to say, Amp=Big.

Comment: That is exactly what I feel. I expect that for high Picard numbers and under some additional condition, all example should be abelian varieties or abelian variety fibration or may be a quotient of them. 

Comment: Thinking a little more, what I said works just as well for any homogeneous variety. Do those fit into your classification?

Comment: I don't have any classification in mind, I am looking for one.


Comment: Yes, I was just referring to your statement in the previous comment: "I expect that for high Picard numbers and under some additional condition, all example should be abelian varieties or abelian variety fibration or may be a quotient of them."

Answer (score 5):

If you consider the case of smooth surfaces then $Big(X)=Amp(X)$ if and only if $X$ has no curves with negative self-intersection. The point is that for surfaces the closers of these two cones are dual.

Comment: Yes, for the surfaces the answer is easier to understand and somehow (may be not precisely) such surfaces are minimal surfaces. Things get more difficult and more interesting in dimension three.

The things I like to know is whether this condition means $X$ is minimal? How big the Picard number can be in this case? What if $X$ is also smooth? 

Comment: For example, if $X$ is Calabi-Yau 3-fold, this would imply that the boundary of ample cone is a subset of cubic cone (similar to dimension 2 for which boundary of ample cone would lie on conic cone) and as far as I now there is no known example of such C.Y of Picard number bigger than two.

Comment: Mohammad, it depends on what you call minimal. For example, take the surface $C\times C$, where $C$ is a curve of genus $>1$. Then it is minimal according to standard terminology (you agree of course?). But the diagonal of this surface has negative self-intersection, this is why for this surface $Big(X)\ne Amp(X)$. I'll think about your further questions. But it should be correct indeed that manifolds with $Big(X)=Amp(X)$ has to be minimal. 

Comment: As soon as $X$ admits a proper morphism $f:X\to Y$ which is generically finite but not finite, then $Big(X)\neq Amp(X)$. Indeed, for any ample line bundle $L$ on $Y$, $f^*L$ is big, but not ample.

Comment: @ACL: Perhaps one needs f to be projective rather than proper since if Y is not projective it does not have any ample line bundles... 

Comment: @Mohammad The Picard number can be arbitrarily large (without the CY) condition: to get Picard number $n$ it suffices to consider a generic complete intersection of large degree (and dimension at least $2$) in $(\mathbb{P}^1)^n$.

Comment: @ACL: Those kind of maps are birational contractions and correspond to codimension faces of ample cone. As I said, in this case boundary of ample cone lies on cubic cone and so there is no co-dimension one face  and so no contraction. That is why I said such $X$ is minimal.